# find object index by string

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have many html-inputs and a very big object with lots of information.

Many of those inputs are directly linked to a specific string in the object.
E.g.:

```
<input name="alpha_beta_gamma" type="input" val="newstring" />
```

and

```
  obj = {
         alpha: {
             beta: {
                 gamma: 'oldString'
             }
         },
         stuff2: {
             whatever: {
                 weathertoday: 'rainy',
                 sun: false
             },
             phone: '1234567'
         }
  }
```

the checkbox field for the value "sun" would have the name "stuff2_whatever_sun" but the "phone" field the name "stuff2_phone" and the "gamma" input field the name "alpha_beta_gamma".

Hope you guys get me :)

...and I will use a jQuery focusout event:

```
 $('input.specialClass').live('focusout', function(){
      obj[whatevercomeshere] = $(this).val();
 });
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? are you saying the input's name attribute is a method name on some object that you want to call?

Comment: yes. in this case "obj" is the first level, which is always the same, "alpha" is the second, "beta" the third" ect.. the thing is, that it can be two arguments ("alpha_beta") or e.g. seven!

Comment: I am guessing that you are really trying to ask how you are going to index the object in order to properly update it. We can't address an issue like that without understanding your large object. You'll have to be more detailed if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `eval`:

```
$('input').each( 
   function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val(eval("obj." + $this.attr('name').replace(/_/g, '.'));
   }
);
```

Comment: exactly what I needed but backwards. Thanks for the eval tip.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input.specialClass').live('focusout', function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  var o = obj, parts = name.split("_");
  $.each(parts, function(k, v) {
    if(k == parts.length - 1) {
       o[v] = $(this).val();
    } else {
       o = o[v];
    }
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method:

```
    var obj = {},
        name2json = function(o, name, val){
            var prop = name.splice(0, 1);
            o[prop] = o[prop] || {};
            if(name.length === 0){
                o[prop] = val;
            }else{
                name2json(o[prop], name, val);
            }
        };
    $('input.specialClass').live('focusout', function(){
        name2json(obj, this.name.split('_'), this.value);
     });
```